# How to output process stats after completion?

Tags: bash, software-rec, cygwin, statistics, measure

I would like to run a process from `bash` in Cygwin so that I have some short summary after execution like peak memory usage or average CPU usage, like `time` but with more information.

Are there any options?

Comment: OS doesn't matter? I think we would have to choose a Unix- based one here.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Unix is not represented by a single OS. Neither Linux nor Unix are OS's. My remark makes quite a bit of sense considering how many spinoffs these two have and not all programs are universal. I am really not interested in a specific OS.

Comment: Then this question is too broad to answer here. See [Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: @JeffSchaller thereifixedit.

Comment: there are several good related questions, including http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331691/how-much-ram-diskspace-and-cpu-time-is-used-by-a-script?rq=1 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18841/measuring-ram-usage-of-a-program?rq=1

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes those are helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can do this by running the command inside GNU `time`. By default,
>   time shows you the `real` (wall clock), `user` (CPU-seconds used in
>   user mode), and `sys` (CPU-seconds used in kernel mode) data items.
>   However, you can also ask it to measure other things, such as RAM and
>   disk usage:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/time -f "File system outputs: %O\nMaximum RSS size: %M\nCPU percentage used: %P" <command>
> ```
>
> where `<command>` is replaced by the command you wish to run. The
>   output will be something like:
>
> ```
> File system outputs: 18992
> Maximum RSS size: 40056
> CPU percentage used: 367%
> ```
>
> where "CPU percentage used" is a percentage and shows here that 3.6
>   cores were used, "Maximum RSS size" is as close as it gets to "maximum
>   memory used" and is expressed in kilobytes, and "File system outputs"
>   is expressed in number of operations (i.e., it does not say how much
>   data is written). The `du` and `df` commands you gave should help
>   there.
>
> Note: you *need* to use `/usr/bin/time` rather than just `time`, as
>   many shells have that as a builtin, which doesn't necessarily support
>   the `-f` option.
>
> For more information, see `man time`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331707/213127

Same goes for Cygwin: there is a bash built-in which can be substituted by GNU time.

Comment: However, GNU `time` has awfully formatted output and I do not know how to fix it.